# What are some good ways to spend FSA money?

Tags: fsa, healthcare

I have an FSA and contributed $400 to it. I made this decision in October, thinking that I would need some dental work in the coming here. Two weeks after submitting my form, I chipped the tooth and had it fixed out of pocket. I chipped again this week and had it fixed, but the dentist was nice enough to do it for free because it was so soon after the first time. Now I think I'm going to have too much money left over. Barring another injury, what are some good ways to spend my FSA dollars? I wish toothpaste and mouthwash counted.

Comment: Daniel your question sounds alot like http://www.basicallymoney.com/questions/280/how-can-we-use-up-our-flex-spending-account-fsa-before-the-end-of-the-year

Answer (score 9):

Co-Pays. I know, with good medical, that's just $10-$20.
Acupuncture, Chiropractic Care (if not paid by your plan)
Eye Exam, often not covered so well. 
Eye Glasses. Often far higher than the plan pays.

Over the counter drugs (update - starting 2011 these can only be reimbursed if they are prescribed, probably more trouble than it's worth), cold medicine, band-aids, ace bandages, heating pad. Birth control (condoms, foam, sponges, if you are worthy)

Any of those work for you?

Note, regulations permit the FSA administrator to allow up to $500 to rollover to the next year, check if your plan permits this.

Comment: You can't spend FSA dollars on unprescribed medications any more, unfortunately.

Comment: When answered in 2010, that was not the case. You are now correct, and I edited my answer to reflect 2011 law.

Comment: I'm going to upvote you just for taking a minute to edit a year-old post.

Comment: Also: Any medical costs that you need to pay before your deductable has been met, if your health insurance has a deductable.